# Setup file created but not working on other computer

Tags: c#

I want to create setup with accesss database.I have created but while I am trying to insatl on any computer its working fine but when I am accessing the database I get an error message

> "D:/TMS/TMS/TMS_Database.accdb" not found on the server,write correct path for database

My connection string class like bellow.

```
class ConnectionString
{
  public string DBConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\TMS\TMS\TMS_Database.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";

    }
```

please solve my problem based on this condition. i want create database path.that should run on every insatlled system

Comment: sir but i want to create connection string for database which will work on every system

Answer (score -1):

If you're deploying your application, you should make sure that all necessary resources (images, files, databases, etc.) are available on end-user system. In your case, don't use fully qualified path to the database file, use relative path instead (providing the database file is in the app's, current directory):

```
public string DBConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=TMS_Database.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
```

Answer (score -1):

there must be TMS_Database.accdb file on client system  at location "D:\TMS\TMS". so you have to place TMS_Database.accdb on this location. But this is not the very write thing. you need to correct the connection string and must be look like:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="CustomerDataConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
      Data Source=|DataDirectory|Northwind.mdb"
    providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

take reference of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hktw939c%28v=vs.85%29.aspx